# Interface method marked as Obsolete does not issue a message from the compiler when implemented

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Consider this example

```
    public interface IAnimal
    {
        [Obsolete("Animals can't eat anymore", true)]
        void Eat();
    }

    public class Animal : IAnimal
    {
        public void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
```

I have an interface IAnimal with an obsoleted method.
The Class Animal implements that interface.

Later on, i call the Eat method as such:

```
var animal = new Animal();
animal.Eat();
```

The compiler does not fail to compile (i have Obsolete marked to give an error instead of an warning).
The program compiles and the method is invoked with no errors, as well.

As far as i can see this is a bug from the compiler. Am i missing anything?

Note: i am using VS2010

Comment: This is not a compiler bug.

Comment: @EricLippert: if i had marked obsolete as warning shouldn't the compiler provide a warning to whoever implements it? I understand marking obsolete to give an error can be a corner case

Comment: That's not a compiler bug either. You didn't mark `Animal.Eat` obsolete, you marked `IAnimal.Eat` obsolete. You used `Animal.Eat`, which might not be obsolete.

Comment: The problem is the use of var instead of explicitly declaring the object type as IAnimal. Thanks to @DocMax for providing a clear explanation. Declaring the type explicitly does result in the expected warning.

Comment: The problem with claiming this isn't a bug in the way this inheritance was designed is that this design causes a HUGE maintenance problem with interfaces. Instead of marking the Interface Obsolete and signaling to everyone down the chain that they NEED to stop using the deprecated method, you additionally now have to modify every single implementation that exists of that interface. The `Animal` author may want to *ADD* the method to their specific implementation of `IAnimal`, but that's less relevant while the interface exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've only marked IAnimal.Eat as obsolete, not Animal.Eat. The *var* keyword resolves to Animal, and so when you call animal.Eat, you're not calling into any method marked as Obsolete.

To fix, either explicitly change *var* to *IAnimal*, or better still, mark Animal.Eat as obsolete as well:

```
    public interface IAnimal
    {
        [Obsolete("Animals can't eat anymore", true)]
        void Eat();
    }

    public class Animal : IAnimal
    {
        [Obsolete("Animals can't eat anymore", true)]
        public void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this *works*, there are two issues: a) Now you're using an explicit type instead of `var`, and b) What happens if you don't control all the implementations of `IAnimal` and people downstream continue using the deprecated functionality? Sure, this isn't an immediate issue if they're using `Animal` explicitly, but one day they decide to use a different `IAnimal` and the rug is pulled out from under them when the expected interface is no longer there.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the behavior is because your `var animal` is an `Animal` in which the `Eat` method is not obsolete. If you did:

```
IAnimal animal = new Animal();
animal.Eat();
```

you should see the warning/error that you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler won't warn for obsolete methods from interfaces, only for method calls. There are good reasons for this:

#### You may always name your method `Eat`

You are always allowed to implement a method `Eat` on `Animal` regardless of whether it is also present in one of the interfaces and marked obsolete. For example, if this is allowed:

```
public class Animal
{
    public void Eat() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Why wouldn't this be allowed:

```
public class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat() { /* ... */ }
}
```

#### All interface methods must be implemented

You are required to implement all methods present in an interface. You can't skip any of them, not even when they are obsolete.

For example, if you didn't add `Eat`, you wouldn't have implemented *all* members of the interface and you'd get other errors:

```
public class Animal : IAnimal
{
    // No Eat()
}
```

> 'Animal' does not implement interface member 'IAnimal.Eat()'

Comment: The second reason is the big one.  The author of an interface may wish to discourage people from using a particular method, but the system's going to insist that every class that claims to implement an interface must implement every member whether or not anyone uses it.

Comment: The second reason doesn't make any sense here. Even if the method must be implemented, the deprecation warning should be issued to code _calling_ the deprecated method. The method on the implementation class could simply be a no-op method, or throw a NotImplementedException when called.